# Isito Ingress Controller Virtual Service returning 503

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio

I have created an AKS cluster with below versions.

```
Kubernetes version: 1.12.6
Istio version: 1.1.4
Cloud Provider: Azure
```

I have also successfully installed Istio as my Ingress gateway with an external IP address. I have also enabled istio-injection for the namespace where I have deployed my service. and I see that the sidecar injection is happening successfully. it is showing.

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
club-finder-deployment-7dcf4479f7-8jlpc   2/2     Running   0          11h
club-finder-deployment-7dcf4479f7-jzfv7   2/2     Running   0          11h
```

My tls-gateway

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: tls-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

**Note: I am using self-signed certs for testing.**

I have applied below virtual service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: club-finder-service-rules
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  # https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService
  gateways: # The default `mesh` value for when left blank is doesn't seem to propigate the rule properly. For now, always use a list of FQDN gateways
    - tls-gateway
  hosts:
    - "*" # APIM Manager URL
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev/clubfinder/service/clubs
    rewrite:
      uri: /v1/clubfinder/clubs/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: club-finder.club-finder-service-dev.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev/clubfinder/service/status
    rewrite:
      uri: /status
    route:
    - destination:
        host: club-finder.club-finder-service-dev.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
```

Now when I am trying to test my service using Ingress external IP like

```
curl -kv https://<external-ip-of-ingress>/dev/clubfinder/service/status
```

I get below error

```
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fe5e800d600)
> GET /dev/clubfinder/service/status HTTP/2
> Host: x.x.x.x --> Replacing IP intentionally
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 503 
< date: Tue, 07 May 2019 05:15:01 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
< 
* Connection #0 to host x.x.x.x left intact
```

Can someone please point me out what is wrong here

Comment: show the logs from the ingress pod? did you create an actual ingress deployment?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Which Ingress pod you want me to show the logs from. pilot, sidecar or ingressgateway?

Comment: ingress pod, my comment says that...

Comment: there is no ingress deployment but i do have istio deployments. sorry can you please specify which pod you want the logs from. @4c74356b41

Comment: for istio gateway to work you need to create ingress pods, else what would serve the traffic

Comment: @4c74356b41 - For istio we deploy 2 things one is Gateway which is like ingress loadbalancer and then VirtualService which defines the routes for the service

Comment: you also need pod that would be a gateway.

Comment: because the response says `server: istio-envoy` the problem probably happens after the ingress. Can you please show the service `club-finder.club-finder-service-dev`?
To add to the comment of @4c74356b41, Gateway object is a config for the ingressgateway. You need to have `istio-ingressgateway-<rs-hash>-<pod-hash>` pods in `istio-system`, you can check this pod's logs to see if they show any problem.

Comment: @Olga - I was able to make it working. I was wrongly configuring port 8080 instead of 80 in my Gateway configuration. after updating it started working.

Comment: Hi, @ShantanooK. If you figure out the solution or the mistake, you can add the answer for others which looking for it.

Comment: could you please share you  kind: IstioOperator ?

Answer (score 5):

I was incorrectly defining my "VirtualService" yaml. Instead of using default HTTP port 80 i was mentioning 8080 which is my applications listening port. Below yaml worked for me

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: club-finder-service-rules
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  # https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#VirtualService
  gateways: # The default `mesh` value for when left blank is doesn't seem to propigate the rule properly. For now, always use a list of FQDN gateways
    - tls-gateway
  hosts:
    - "*" # APIM Manager URL
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev/clubfinder/service/clubs
    rewrite:
      uri: /v1/clubfinder/clubs/
    route:
    - destination:
        host: club-finder.club-finder-service-dev.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /dev/clubfinder/service/status
    rewrite:
      uri: /status
    route:
    - destination:
        host: club-finder.club-finder-service-dev.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

Comment: the problem is on his kind: IstioOperator

Comment: I have a question, after changing the port number in `VirtualService` did you change also  in ingress gateway port configuration?

Comment: @shammir - No, just in VS

Answer (score 2):

For the future reference, if you have issue like this, there are basically two main steps to troubleshoot:

1) Check Envoy proxies are up and their configs are synchronized with Pilot

```
istioctl proxy-config
```

2) Get Envoy's listeners for your pod and see if anything is listening a port on which your service is running

```
istioctl proxy-config listener club-finder-deployment-7dcf4479f7-8jlpc
```

So, in your case at step #2 you would see that there was no listener for port 80 , pointing out to a root cause.

Also, if you'd take a look to envoy logs, you'd probably see errors with **UF (upstream failure)** or **UH (No healthy upstream)** code. Here is a full [list](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/access_log) of error flags.

For a more deep Envoy debugging refer to this [handbook](https://istio.io/help/ops/traffic-management/proxy-cmd/)